# Tilting in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to tilt my object left or right depending on which side I'm tilting my phone while object is moving forward,here is my code which is not working properly..

```
void Update () {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.acceleration.x > 1) {
        transform.Rotate(90,0,0);
    }
    else if (Input.acceleration.x < -1) {
        transform.Rotate(-90,0,0);
    }
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [smooth](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html) the accelerometer data before using it. Otherwise, the `GameObect` will be shaking or noisy while tilting the device.

You just need to convert the accelerometer value to `Quaternion` with `Quaternion.Euler` then assign the value directly to `transform.localRotation` of the GameObect.

```
int MIN = 0;
int MAX = 100;
public bool flipDirection = false;
public bool smoothAccelerometer = true;

float defaultZValue;

//Filter Accelerometer
float AccelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0f / 30.0f;
float LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds = 1.0f;
float LowPassFilterFactor = 0;
Vector3 lowPassValue = Vector3.zero;

void Start()
{
    defaultZValue = transform.position.z;

    //Filter Accelerometer
    LowPassFilterFactor = AccelerometerUpdateInterval / LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds;
    lowPassValue = Input.acceleration;
}


void Update()
{
    //Move Object
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);

    //Get smoothed Accelerometer value values (pass in false to use raw Accelerometer values)
    Vector3 dir = LowPassFilterAccelerometer(smoothAccelerometer);

    if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    {
        //Check if right
        if (dir.x > 0)
        {
            float angle = mapValue(dir.x, 0f, 1f, MIN, MAX);
            if (flipDirection)
            {
                angle = angle * -1;
            }
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
        }
        //Check if left
        else if (dir.x < 0)
        {
            float angle = mapValue(dir.x, -0f, -1f, -MIN, -MAX);
            if (flipDirection)
            {
                angle = angle * -1;
            }
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
        }
        //Middle(No direction)
        else
        {
            //Use Default Angle
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, defaultZValue);
        }
    }
}

float mapValue(float mainValue, float inValueMin, float inValueMax, float outValueMin, float outValueMax)
{
    return (mainValue - inValueMin) * (outValueMax - outValueMin) / (inValueMax - inValueMin) + outValueMin;
}

//Filter Accelerometer
Vector3 LowPassFilterAccelerometer(bool smooth)
{
    if (smooth)
        lowPassValue = Vector3.Lerp(lowPassValue, Input.acceleration, LowPassFilterFactor);
    else
        lowPassValue = Input.acceleration;

    return lowPassValue;
}
```

Comment: **Note**: If it's not working, say what's not working. Don't just say it's not working. That's won't be helpful to me.

Comment: Sorry for the late.Yea I've checked it and its not tilting.

Answer (score 0):

use these instead:

```
private Quaternion localRotation;
public float speed = 1.0f;
void Start () 
{
localRotation = transform.rotation;
}
void Update()
{
float curSpeed = Time.deltaTime * speed;

localRotation.y += Input.acceleration.x * curSpeed;
localRotation.x += Input.acceleration.y * curSpeed;

transform.rotation = localRotation;
}
```

for gamedev q&a : [stackexchange gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)